# How to enable autocomplete in gmail login screen

Tags: internet-explorer, autocomplete

My gmail login screen used to autocomplete my username and password.  Now it does not. I have checked my Internet Explorer internet settings and verified that autocomplete is turned on, but still no  autocomplete when I logon to gmail.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Auto-complete for form fields can be suppressed via the HTML on a webpage. Some password managers ignore it, but most of the ones built into browsers honor it (to be standards-compliant). I use an excellent free third-party password manager called [LastPass](http://lastpass.com) which fills out my gmail login page completely.